# Liferay permissions on web content

Tags: permissions, liferay

I have created role (content editor) who is able to edit journal articles.

In our application we have homepage with web-content(journal article) and we need to disable editing only this web content to all roles (except admin role).

How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: If it is single Web-Content then Go to Control Panel > Web Content, click on Permission action for your Web-Content and uncheck permissions to except admin user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried that, but content_editor (our new role) has **bold** disabled checkboxes **bold** it is not possible to uncheck them :(

Comment: If the content editor has removed their own permissions to edit (or set permission on) this content, you'll need an administrator or somebody else who still has the required permissions on that article.

Comment: It is not working because permissions were defined for role so then it is not possible to modify this permissions exactly on some web content. (Checkboxes will be disabled for that role.)